# How do I disable "eager" validation entirely using jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Is there a way to disable "eager" validation using the jquery.validate plugin? Either through an option in the script or as a hack?  "Eager" validation kicks in once the form has been validated once - after that, invalid fields are validated onfocusout.  I want to disable this behavior, and change my forms to only be validated when the submit button is pressed.

I don't mind hacking through the validate script itself also, so if that's what the solution requires that's acceptable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the onfocusout option.

**onfocusout, boolean, default:true**

*"Validate elements (except checkboxes/radio buttons) on blur. If nothing is entered, all rules are skipped, except when the field was already marked as invalid."*

[About halfway down](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options).

So to disable "eager" validation:

```
$(".selector").validate({
  onfocusout: false
});
```