# JQuery Validate Plugin - Eager validation on custom method when should be lazy

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The validate plugin seems to be eagerly validating on a custom method I have when it should be lazy, all other validation occurs lazily (i.e. not until the form is submitted).

The custom method:

```
$.validator.addMethod("refDataAcInput", function(value, element)
{
    return ($(element).val() == "" || $(element).data("hasValidSelectedValue") != null);
}, "The item must be a valid selected item.");
```

Validate plugin init:

```
this.$form.validate({
    ignore: null,
    invalidHandler : function()
    {
        _self.initUnsavedChangesWarning.ignorePageLeaveReq = false;
        _self.setValidationMsgVisible(true);

        $("body,html").scrollTop($("#cmFormErrorReport").position().top);
    },
    submitHandler :function(form)
    {
        //Disable form submit button - prevent duplicate request for impatient users
        $("button[type=submit]", form).prop("disabled", true);
        form.submit();
    },
    showErrors : function(errorMap, errorList)
    {
        _self.updateErrors(errorList);
        this.defaultShowErrors();
    },
    errorPlacement : function(error, $element)
    {
        $element.parents("tr").children(".fieldError").append(error);
    },
    errorClass : "jqueryError"
});
```

Any ideas how to make this occur lazily?

Comment: Use this [post][1] ' s answer. It works great.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706778/how-do-i-disable-eager-validation-entirely-using-jquery-validate

Comment: @Samson, that answer has nothing to do with "lazy validation"; `onfocusout:false` simply disables the `onblur` event for every field at all times.  The OP is only having trouble getting the default behavior to work on one field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've built the `required` rule into your custom method.

```
$.validator.addMethod("refDataAcInput", function(value, element) {
    return ($(element).val() == "" || $(element).data("hasValidSelectedValue") != null);
}, "The item must be a valid selected item.");
```

Remove `$(element).val() == ""` and replace with `this.optional(element)`...

```
$.validator.addMethod("refDataAcInput", function(value, element) {
    return (this.optional(element) || $(element).data("hasValidSelectedValue") != null);
}, "The item must be a valid selected item.");
```

Then if you also want the field to be `required`, just declare the `required` rule along with your custom `refDataAcInput` rule.

The plugin's default "Lazy" validation should now be working as expected.